# I can't see analysis results of SonarQube

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonarqube with jenkins. The execution is successful but I don´t see any report or result. Everything is 0.

I think the problem is here, but I am not sure.

```
16:01:05 16:01:05.380 WARN: This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
16:01:05 16:01:05.380 INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=625ms
16:01:05 16:01:05.380 INFO: Sensor C# (wrapped)
16:01:05 16:01:05.396 INFO: Importing analysis results from C:\Jenkins\jobs\firecom_backend\workspace\null\output-cs
16:01:05 16:01:05.411 WARN: Protobuf file not found: null\output-cs\encoding.pb
16:01:05 16:01:05.427 WARN: Protobuf file not found: null\output-cs\metrics.pb
16:01:05 16:01:05.427 WARN: Protobuf file not found: null\output-cs\issues.pb
16:01:05 16:01:05.427 WARN: Protobuf file not found: null\output-cs\token-type.pb
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 WARN: Protobuf file not found: null\output-cs\symrefs.pb
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 WARN: Protobuf file not found: null\output-cs\token-cpd.pb
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 INFO: Sensor C# (wrapped) (done) | time=62ms
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 INFO: Sensor C# Unit Tests Coverage Report Import (wrapped)
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 DEBUG: No coverage property. Skip Sensor
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 INFO: Sensor C# Unit Tests Coverage Report Import (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 INFO: Sensor C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import (wrapped)
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 DEBUG: No coverage property. Skip Sensor
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 INFO: Sensor C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import (wrapped)
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 DEBUG: No unit test results property. Skip Sensor
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
16:01:05 16:01:05.442 INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (wrapped)
16:01:05 16:01:05.474 INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=32ms
16:01:05 16:01:05.474 INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (wrapped)
16:01:05 16:01:05.505 INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=31ms
16:01:05 16:01:05.505 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (wrapped)
16:01:05 16:01:05.505 INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for cs
16:01:05 16:01:05.505 DEBUG: No CpdMapping for language cs
16:01:05 16:01:05.505 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
16:01:05 16:01:05.505 INFO: Calculating CPD for 0 files
16:01:05 16:01:05.505 INFO: CPD calculation finished
16:01:08 16:01:08.692 INFO: Analysis report generated in 3094ms, dir size=276 KB
16:01:09 16:01:09.364 INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 672ms, zip size=150 KB
16:01:09 16:01:09.364 INFO: Analysis report generated in C:\Jenkins\jobs\firecom_backend\workspace\.scannerwork\batch-report
16:01:09 16:01:09.364 DEBUG: Upload report
```

There is a folder called null, maybe this is the problem but I don't know solve it.

My sonar.properties are:

```
sonar.projectKey=mykey
sonar.projectName=myproject
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=cs
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.analysis.mode        
sonar.verbose=true
```

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to downgrade the plugin of C# but I do not find where.

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: sonarqube 5.6.6  -   C# 6.0.0.2033

Comment: Have a look at the [sourcecode](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-dotnet-shared-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/dotnet/shared/plugins/EncodingPerFile.java). It looks like a report directory must be configured.

Comment: Sorry, where do I have to change the code?

Comment: I see that `sonar.analysis.mode` is unset. Maybe try with `sonar.analysis.mode=publish`

Comment: I tried sonar.analysis.mode=publish but nothing. The same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same to me in the combinations: sonarqube 5.6.6 - C# 6.0.0.2033
Downgraded C# plugin to 5.4.0.464 and analysis is working. I would like to use latest version :)

Comment: Add more details to support your answer. Flagged in [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16555464)

Comment: Thanks but where can I find the previous version of the plugin?

Comment: You can find the releases [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/releases). I can confirm, that SonarQube 5.6.6 works with C# plugin 5.4.0.457 and sonar-runner.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using sonar-scanner (w/o MsBuild).
Since version 6.0 of sonar-csharp-plugin, it supports only
sonar-scanner-msbuild.

You should migrate to MsBuild scanner or downgrade to 5.X.X version of plugin.